# How to populate results of EXECUTE (@myQuery) AT [LinkedServer] Into Temp Table from Oracle Query

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have a linked Oracle server within MSSQL Server, and I'm trying to return the results of a query into a temp table. The query is over 8,000 characters, so I can't use the OPENQUERY() I normally use. I can run the below, and see results since RPC is enabled.

```
/*
Declare query variable, since query is more than 8,000 characters
*/
DECLARE @myQuery VARCHAR(MAX)

/*
Set query
*/
SET @myQuery = 'Query text here'

EXECUTE (@myQuery) AT ServerName
```

What I've tried so far:

```
/* 
Declare query variable, since query is more than 8,000 characters 
*/ 
DECLARE @myQuery VARCHAR(max) 

/* 
Create temp table 
*/ 
CREATE TABLE ##temptable
  ( 
     field NVARCHAR(50) 
  ) 

/* 
Set query 
*/ 
SET @myQuery = 'Query text here' 

INSERT INTO temptable(field)
EXECUTE (@myQuery) at servername
```

However, that returns the following error message from MSSQL:

> OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "ServerName"
>   returned message "Unable to enlist in the transaction.". Msg 7391,
>   Level #, State #, Line # The operation could not be performed
>   because OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "ServerName"
>   was unable to begin a distributed transaction.

Any help/direction would be really appreciated.

**Update**

I've tried the below, and it returns the same message.

```
/*  
Declare query variable, since query is more than 8,000 characters
*/  
DECLARE @myQuery VARCHAR(max) 

/*  
Set query  
*/  
SET @myQuery = 'Query text here' 

DECLARE @table TABLE(  field NVARCHAR(50) ) 

INSERT INTO @table(field)
EXECUTE (@myQuery) at servername
```

Comment: Have you tried  table variable instead of temp table?

Comment: @PeterHE Yes; I've tried to declare a table, with the field, and insert into it and I get the same message back.

Comment: You can try to wrap the remote call sql to Oracle t in an SP (sp1), and call that SP in your main SP like:  INSERT EXEC sp1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to anyone coming here in the future, I was able to resolve the issue with the following:

The first is set the Local DTC – see Windows Server 2012 Distributed Transaction Coordinator.

The second was, in the Properties of each linked server, set the “Enable Promotion of Distributed Transactions” to FALSE.